# SAS Checking Whether A Third Variable is Between the Values of two other variables

Tags: variables, compare, sas, row

I have been dealing with this issue that I thought was trivial, but for some reason nothing I have tried has worked so far.

I have a dataset

```
obs A B C
1   2 6 7
2   3 1 5
3   8 5 9
.   . . .
```

For each observation, I want to compare the values in column A to the values in column B and assign a value 1 to a variable called within. My goal to only select observations where their A value is within their B and C values. I have tried everything, but nothing seem to be working.

Thank you.

Comment: can you better explain the layout of your data?  Do you have three variables or 1?

Comment: Sorry, the formatting messed up.

Comment: can you fix it?  Why not just do this in a data step?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it in a data step.  Let me know if that works for you.

```
data new;
set old;
if B < A < C then D = 1;
else delete;
run;
```

Comment: Sorry, I have been trying to fix the formatting, but it does not seem to be working.  I tried what you suggested but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: do you have three variables in your dataset named A, B and C?  I just ran the above code is SAS and it worked.  What specific problem are you encountering?

Comment: Yes, A B C are the variables, and for each observation, I want to delete if A does not lie between B and C. Thank you for the help.

Comment: ok, I just changed the code to delete the ones you don't want

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked now, but I can swear that I did exact same thing earlier, but it was not working. I resorted to writing macros to deal with it, but I was thinking this should be trivial.